# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named X error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to run an empty Spring application with mvc and hibernate. 
I'm stuck on the hibernate part, for some reason I keep getting the below error.
It seems from the logs like hibernate tries to connect to the database but fails, I have no idea what can be wrong.
The database I use is local instance of MySQL8. The settings (such as character encoding, timezone etc) are correct and I have no trouble connecting to it with JDBC.

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in pl.coderslab.app.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named tesPersistenceUnit
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="tesPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tes"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="very very secret"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

AppConfig.java:

```
package pl.coderslab.app;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pl.coderslab")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setPersistenceUnitName("tesPersistenceUnit");
        return emfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        return tm;
    }

}
```

SpringDiApplication:

```
package pl.coderslab.app;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class SpringDiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        context.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.coderslab</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring01hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

full run logs:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=58157:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Olga\IdeaProjects\Spring01hibernate\target\classes;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.1.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.12\byte-buddy-1.8.12.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.3.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Olga\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.39\mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar" pl.coderslab.app.SpringDiApplication
mar 04, 2020 11:43:30 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@b81eda8: startup date [Wed Mar 04 23:43:30 CET 2020]; root of context hierarchy
mar 04, 2020 11:43:30 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'tesPersistenceUnit'
mar 04, 2020 11:43:30 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: tesPersistenceUnit
    ...]
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tes]
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****, characterEncoding=utf8}
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mar 04, 2020 11:43:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Wed Mar 04 23:43:31 CET 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
mar 04, 2020 11:43:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
mar 04, 2020 11:43:32 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
mar 04, 2020 11:43:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
mar 04, 2020 11:43:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
mar 04, 2020 11:43:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Could not create connection to database server.
mar 04, 2020 11:43:32 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in pl.coderslab.app.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named tesPersistenceUnit
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in pl.coderslab.app.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named tesPersistenceUnit
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at pl.coderslab.app.SpringDiApplication.main(SpringDiApplication.java:7)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named tesPersistenceUnit
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 11 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In which directory you have saved your persistance.xml. It should be in `resource/META-INF/` .

Answer (score 0):

try to add to pom.xml this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```